# C++ declared nested structure

Tags: c++, structure

i have this structure in C++ program:

```
 struct strSettings{
        struct strTargetParam{
            double procPP;
            double procTL;
        };
        struct str_tresh{
            strTargetParam H;
            strTargetParam L;
        }thresh;    
    }settings;
```

Why is it possible to declare the following:

```
settings.thresh.H.procPP = 0.2;
settings.thresh.H.procTL = 0.1;
```

Is it because the nested structure str_thresh is already direclty declared?

Comment: Why shouldn’t it work? What are you expecting instead? What do you mean by “directly declared”?

Comment: Once the compiler's seen the definition of a struct you can use that struct, that's kind of the point.

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/

Comment: typo - str_tresh changed to/from str_thresh? Please review MCVE

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your code in detail.  First, the outer `struct`:

```
struct strSettings { ... } settings;
```

This statement defines a `struct` of type `strSettings`, and immediately declares a *variable*, called `settings`, of this `struct` type.  Now we look inside:

```
struct strSettings {
    struct strTargetParam { ... };    // 1
    struct str_thresh { ... } thresh; // 2
} settings;
```

You define two nested `structs`, the first one of type `strTargetParam` (above marked with comment `// 1`), and the second one of type `str_thresh` (above marked with comment `// 2`), which in turn has two members of type `strTargetParam`.  As before, for the second struct you immediately declare a member variable of type `str_thresh`, which is called `thresh`.

The following code is equivalent to yours and maybe makes things more clear:

```
struct strSettings {
    // Define a nested struct
    struct strTargetParam {
        double procPP;
        double procTL;
    };
    // Define another nested struct
    struct str_tresh {
        strTargetParam H; // members of first nested struct type
        strTargetParam L;
    };

    // Separately define your thresh member
    str_thresh thresh;
};

// Separately define your main object
strSettings settings;
```

So, `settings` is of type `strSettings`, which has a member `thresh` of type `strSettings::str_thresh`, which in turn has members `H` and `L` of type `strSettings::strTargetParam`.

Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're defining all variable names you use.

`settings` is defined to be:

```
struct strSettings{
    struct strTargetParam{
        double procPP;
        double procTL;
    };
    struct str_tresh{
        strTargetParam H;
        strTargetParam L;
    } thresh;    
}
```

which has a member `thresh` which is defined to be:

```
struct str_tresh{
    strTargetParam H;
    strTargetParam L;
}
```

which has a member `H` defined to be:

```
struct strTargetParam{
    double procPP;
    double procTL;
};
```

which in turn has members `procPP` and `procTL` both defined to be `double`s.

So `settings.thresh.H.procPP` and `settings.thresh.H.procTL` are known to be `double`s.